# Detect when an external third party program is about to exit

Tags: c#-4.0, process

I need to run a third party program from c# (using .Net Framework 4) and take a screen shot right before it exits. I start the program with `Process.Start()`. Is there any way to detect that the program is about to exit? I know about the `Process.Exited` but that is too late.

Thanks 
Tom

Comment: The event you discovered is the only event that exists.  Please note there is a million and half ways to end a process that even that event won't register.  When you register and watch `Process.Exited` you only are notified when the event actually happens, if you force the process to end, the process doesn't report to Windows that it ended ( Windows already knows ).

Answer (score 1):

1 Wait end of treatment

You can use this code - based on `WaitForExit` method

```
process.Start("...");
...
process.WaitForExit();
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx

2 End of treatment

```
process.Terminated +=
    new Win32Process.ProcessInfo.TerminatedEventHandler(...);
```